# The effect of increasing concentration of a cathode solution on the voltage in a galvanic cell

Tags: concentration

I am having trouble understanding a concept. In a galvanic cell, where electrolyte A is zinc (in a solution of zinc nitrate) and electrolyte B is copper (in a solution of copper (II) nitrate), why does voltage increase when the concentration of the copper solution increase? I know that copper is a cathode while zinc is an anode and the cathode solution is the one with the increasing concentration. I also believe that a redox reaction and equilibrium are involved in this concept but not understand how they apply?

Overall, why does voltage increase when the concentration of the cathode solution increase? what does the redox reaction have to do with this?

If it helps, the solution in Salt Bridge is 2.00 M Sodium Nitrate.

Comment: Look at the Daniell cell in my answer [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/118744/79678). The Nernst equation, given directly under the cell schematic, gives the cell potential. So, as per the math, increasing the copper ion concentration increases the cell potential.

Comment: Saying "electrolyte X is <metal>" is wrong description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you can look at. First, we can write out the reaction as a whole: $\ce{Zn + Cu^2+ \rightarrow Zn^2+ + Cu}$

the nernst-equation is given by:
$\ce{E = E^\circ} - \ce{\frac{RT}{nF}lnQ}$, where $\ce{Q = \frac{[Zn^2+]}{[Cu^2+]}}$. We can see that if we increase $\ce{[Cu^2+]}$, we decreases the log value which then increases $\ce{E_{non-standard}}$.

You can also just think of it like this. Since $\ce{Cu^2+}$ is in the reactants, increasing its concentration will shift the equilibrium to the right by Le-Chatelier's principle.